# Automatically instantiate AngularJS controller nested in templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

I'm just learning Angular and have a very basic app set up. When rendering some data via the templateUrl property of a route, what would be the best way to include a sub-controller in the returned template? For example, including a "createOrEditItem" template at the bottom of a "viewItem" template so that the "createOrEditItem" can be reused on its own later?

I've tried putting a `div` in the template with its `ng-controller` attribute set to a controller name that I've defined at the app level, but it's not being activated. Should this be done with a directive instead to make it instantiate when the master controller has its contents set, or am I missing something more fundamental?

Comment: `via the templateUrl property of a controller`? AFAIK, controllers don't have templateUrls..

Comment: maybe you are looking for a nested directives kind of thing.. check [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/mUXCd7/) out for basic example of that

Comment: Thanks - I meant route not controller, and have edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, as mentioned in the later part of the question, you should be using a `directive`. Or, if using AngularJS >= v1.5, `component` should be the choice because they are pluggable and works well with nesting too.

Note that for the route also, you can directly use a `component` like this:

```
var myMod = angular.module('myMod', ['ngRoute']);
myMod.component('home', {
  template: '<h1>Home</h1><p>Hello, {{ $ctrl.user.name }} !</p>',
  //                    ^^^^ other components can be used here
  controller: function() {
    this.user = {name: 'world'};
  } 
});

myMod.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: '<home></home>'
  });
});
```

Now, as the comment suggests, you can freely use other components in the template of `home` component.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: This was absolutely what I wanted! Components seem like the way forward then. Minimal fussing with controllers and a good amount of reuse?

Comment: @tags2k correct! And, even from the forward compatibility (with Angular2 and 4) point of view, components are the way to go! Glad that helped a little..

Answer (score 0):

A directive can be used.

Another option is to use a seperate view/route. So when you add a ui-view tag, you could define your view and route.

This is explained here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router